# Sticky Footer Glitch

Tags: html, css

I have created a sticky footer, a footer that hugs the bottom of the window whether or not there is enough content to fill the page. My implementation works well except for one minor issue when rendering in Internet Explorer. If the content fills the page and any of my content divs have an unspecified height, a crack appears beneath the footer. This also happens if the content contains a span with or without a fixed height.

Below is my implementation. If I give Div 2 a fixed height the footer tightly hugs the bottom of the window, but by not setting a height the crack appears. I have been unable to resolve this. Any suggestions on how to prevent it would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Sticky Footer</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        Html, body {
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: lightgreen;
        }
        header {
            height: 40px;
            background-color: green;
        }
        footer {
            bottom: 0;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 40px;
            background-color: gray;       
        }
        .fixedHeightDiv {
            border: 2px;
            border-style: solid;
            height: 500px;
        }
        .container {
            min-height: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }
        .content {
            padding-bottom: 40px;
        }        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>Header</header>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="fixedHeightDiv">
                Div 1
            </div>
            <div>
                Div 2
            </div>
            <div class="fixedHeightDiv">
                Div 3
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>Footer</footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute`?

Comment: Looks okay in IE11. What version are you using?

Comment: While that does remove the crack, it also forces the footer to be viewed at all times. I do not want the footer taking up space if the content exceeds the window height.

Comment: I am using IE11. The crack is thin and not overly noticeable. I realize this is a very picky question, but I would prefer a completely snug fit if possible.